# Use array as X axis and not having it show up as "Series 1"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a line graph and I use a 2d array with three arrays in it. The first one contain dates and it's supposed to be the X axis, the next two is the data that should be shown as lines on the graph. Everything works as it should, except for one thing. On the side of the graph you see the names of three series, "Series1" (the dates), "Delivery speed" and "Delivery Average". I only want to show the names of the last two series not the first one.

Is it possible to only use the first array as the X axis only and not have it show up as a label?

Here's the code:

```
Set myChart = Graf.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=20, Top:=53, Width:=1000, Height:=400)
    With myChart.Chart
        For i = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 2)
            If i = 1 Then
                ReDim actualdate(1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)) As Date
                For j = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)
                    actualdate(j) = AllDataLists(j, i)
                Next j
            Else
                ReDim actualdata(1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)) As Integer
                For j = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)
                    actualdata(j) = AllDataLists(j, i)
                Next j
            End If

                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            If i = 1 Then
                .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = actualdate
            Else
                
                .SeriesCollection(i).Values = actualdata
                .SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlLine
                .SeriesCollection(i).Name = NewDataLabel(i - 1)
            End If
            
            
            .SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 1
            
            
        Next i
    End With
```

`actualdate` is the array with the dates. `actualdata` is the array with the data. `NewDataLabel` is an array containing the strings "Delivery Speed" and "Delivery Average". `AllDataLists` is the 2d array that contains all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the "NewSeries" command for the x-Axis (i=1)!

```
Sub AddChart2()

    Dim myChart
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=20, Top:=53, Width:=1000, Height:=400)
    
    With myChart.Chart

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "{43831,43862,43891,43922,43952}"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "{-10,10,30,50,70}"
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY"
    
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "{43831,43862,43891,43922,43952}"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "{-20,20,60,100,140}"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]