# Create clustered bar chart from multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-charts

I want to create a clustered bar chart in excel from a 10x10 array. I already figured out how to create a simple bar chart out of a one dimensional array using seriescollection. It looks like this:

```
   Dim ChartInputNumber() As Variant
    ReDim ChartInputNumber(9)

    Dim ChartInputValue() As Variant
    ReDim ChartInputValue(9)

'Neues Chart Objekt deklarieren
    Dim mychart As ChartObject
    
    'Chart formatieren und mit Daten aus Arrays befüllen
    With ActiveSheet
        Set mychart = .ChartObjects.Add(Range("D6:V35").Cells(1).Left, Range("D6:V35").Cells(1).Top, Range("D6:V35").Width, Range("D6:V35").Height)
        'mychart.Chart.ChartWizard .Cells(1)
        mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartInputValue
        mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ChartInputNumber
        mychart.Chart.HasTitle = True
        mychart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Behälterbestand" & .Cells(1, 2).Value
        mychart.Chart.HasLegend = False
    End With
```

where `ChartInputValue` is a one dimensional array containing the y-values and `ChartInputNumber` contains the declarations for the x-axis.

However, from my websearch I wasn't able so far to find out how to rewrite the code such that it would also work with `ChartInputValue(9,9)`, meaning a 10x10 array.
Basically I want to show 10 bars for each category that is listet in `ChartInputNumber`.

I will continue searching and trying, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. `SeriesCollection` is 1D only, but you can add as many series as you need.

Comment: Does this help? 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104763/use-array-as-x-axis-and-not-having-it -show-up-as-series-1/63105597)